# Bootstrap Header Nav fill container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have moved some buttons around on my navbar, and now it isn't filling the container width fully.

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="header-nav-bar home-slide">
    <nav>

      <button><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>

      <ul class="primary-nav list-unstyled">
        <li class="bg-color"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#">Company</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Price</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to use "container-fluid" however there doesn't appear to be anything that has changed regarding width of the buttons.

The size of the container which the buttons are meant to fill evenly is 1140px in width on a 1920 x 1080 monitor.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using and you need to post your CSS as well.

Comment: Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eomopvte/), and I'm using version  v3.2.0. In the jsfiddle the nav bar doesn't seem to appear properly. I'm having the same issue as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247911/how-to-stretch-elements-of-a-bootstrap-navigation-bar-to-make-use-of-the-entire) however the solutions in that question don't work

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't at least starting off with the default `navbar` structure?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this? Otherwise reply me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <button>  <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="bg-color"><a href="#">Home<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>

            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>


        </li>

        <li class=""><a href="#">Company<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>


            <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>


        </li>

        <li><a href="search-page.html">Search Page</a></li>

          <li> <a href="#">Blog<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>


            <li><a href="blog-list.html">Blog list</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog-post.html">Blog-post</a></li>




        <li><a href="price.html">Price</a></li>
        <li><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have updated the question with more relevant details - sorry to be a pain!