# Bootstrap4 Collapse Menu pushing content

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, bootstrap-4

I did look the other forums and but id didn't solve my problems. What's happening is , at a sm breakpoint in bootstrap the hamburger menu , when clicked , is pushing all the header content ( button + h1 ) to the middle and it's ruining the design of the page , how can i fix this problem?

here's my html code :

```
           <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
              <a class="navbar-brand m-0" href="#">
                <img src="images/Untitled-2.png" style="width:235px">
              </a>

              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" 
                 data-toggle="collapse"         
                  data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" 
                  aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" 
                  aria-expanded="false" 
                  aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>       

              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse 
                id="navbarSupportedContent">

             <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME<span class="sronly">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>

                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
                  </li>

                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                     <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" 
                         id="navbarDropdown" role="button" 
                         datatoggle="dropdown" 
                         aria-haspopup="true" 
                         aria-expanded="false">
                    WORK</a>

                     <div class="dropdown-menu" 
                         arialabelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">GALLERY</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">VIDEO</a>
                     </div> 
                   </li>

                   <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
                   </li>
           </ul>
```

Comment: Please post *all* of the Navbar code

Comment: [How to stretch elements of a Bootstrap navigation bar to make use of the entire width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247911/how-to-stretch-elements-of-a-bootstrap-navigation-bar-to-make-use-of-the-entire). Also `datatoggle` must be `data-toggle`.

Comment: Did the solution from this answer help you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stretch elements of a Bootstrap navigation bar to make use of the entire width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247911/how-to-stretch-elements-of-a-bootstrap-navigation-bar-to-make-use-of-the-entire)